# Chained reverse lookups in Django

Tags: django-models, django-views

I have `[profile]` --M2M--> `[group]` --FK--> `[group category]`.

Given an instance of `[group category]`, I need to retrieve all related `[profile]`.

(In english: I have members belonging to one or more groups, which are in categories. I need to find all the members in a given category of group).

How do I span the ForeignKey and ManytoMany keys in between? No matter how I slice this, I always end up with an expression from which I can't define the next backward relationship.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming something like:

```
object Profile():
    groups = models.ManyToManyField('Group')

object Group():
    category = models.ForeignKey('GroupCategory')
```

You should be able to just query it:

```
profiles = Profile.objects.filter(groups__category=thegroupcategory)
```

Comment: Rob - this is so obvious I feel like I've wasted your time. This worked. Thank you.

Comment: Remembering to reverse your thought process and come at the problem from the other direction is always difficult.